# Looking for a keyboard listener that works everywhere on linux(chromebook)

Tags: linux, python, keyboard, keyboard-listener

have been spending all day looking for a keyboard listener to make a hotkey type thing on chromebook and have been having problems with libraries. I have gotten all the different libraries I could find but none of them work the way I need. I started with the keyboard module but that has the limitation of not working on linux. Then I went to pynput but that does not work outside of the terminal(unless I messed something up, idk). Then I tried curses but I couldnt figure that out. Basically i'm stuck and need help. I'm looking for a keyboard listener that can be waiting for me to press a key no matter what I am doing, if I am browsing internet, in an app, or anything else. Would greatly appreciate if someone could give some tips of libraries that can support my needs. thanks!

Comment: I still dont know what you are looking for. Perhaps tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to find a keyboard listener library that works on linux for python that will work anywhere on my chromebook.  Because for example pynput works well but the moment I minimise the  window it stops working.  I want something that will work in any application.  Thanks!